# Do we need to do server side(web services) validation for input parameters in Android development?

Tags: java, android, web-services, validation, web-development-server

I am a web developer and in web development we have been taught to do both client side and server side validation. In Android programming I am doing the client side validation and showing messages using Toast. After that sending data to web services,

1) should I still do a validation (like password field has min of 6 characters, alphanumeric etc.)  in web services.

What are the best practices with respect to validation in Android development?

Comment: No ! Not Required..

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You should do validation from server side. then the question **why** comes

Client-side validation is always in the sense of providing a better User Experience (UX), so the user doesn't have to submit and reenter information simply because a value in a form isn't valid - it makes things more dynamic.

What could a user do if you do not server-side validate? Anything, depending on how you use their data. You could be allowing users to drop entire databases (or worse, leak them), modify anything they like (or worse, read anything they like. Directory traversal flaws are extremely common entrance points for naughty people), and elevate their privileges at will. Do you want to run this risk? **Not validating user input is like trusting people and not installing locks on your house**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely!

Imagine you add other clients, other than Android, to communicate with your application. Then, by server-side checks, you have the insurance that the checks are consistent. Otherwise, consistency is much harder to achieve.

For example: You add a Website as an additional client (beside your app, like some messangers do), and add checks on the client-side by JavaScript. The user disables JavaScript and puts trash into your database!

Another example: You add a iOS-Client. Your password-requirements change from 6 to 8 letters. Now you have to modify and deliver 2 clients, while with serverside-checks. you only have to update your webservice.

So you get safety for more clients!

Comment: Here the question is about android app validation why did the javascript disabling comes into picture?.

Comment: As an example for a further client, which many developers provide.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @thomas Bohm.  You are thinking of a scenario if the application has more clients in future(like ios, website etc..)  but that is not the whole and sole reason why should do server side validation.

Comment: Right, there are of course more reasons, but I think this is an important one which alone makes it nessescarry to do it serverside. Always think of the future :)

Comment: I would rather say one of the important reasons.